# ElGamal with elliptic curves I

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

It is very interesting to see [@tylo's answer on ElGamal with elliptic curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9990/11926).  Instead of mapping the message to the elliptic curve point it just reduces an elliptic curve point to its $x$ coodrinate. The scheme now becomes like this:

function $x^P$ denotes the $x$ coordinate of a point.

**Encryption:** choose random $k\in F_q$ , then calculate $C=kP$ and $c=x^{kY}$. The ciphertext is the point $C$ and the product $c\cdot m \bmod{q}$.

**Decryption:** From a point $C$ and a value $d$ calculate $c'=x^{xC}$. Retrieve the message with $m=d/c' \bmod{q}$.

Could anyone please clarify if the above scheme is additive homomorphic even if we set the ciphetext to be $c+m \bmod{q}$.

Comment: What is Y in c=x^(kY)? Also, FYI, if you are familiar with latex, you can write equations in latex format so they look nicer. Here is a [basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I went ahead and updated with the math formatting. If I made any mistakes, feel free to correct.

Comment: ouch... I just noticed an error in my answer back there. It should not be "mod $q$", but it should be done in $\mathbb{F_q}$. It's just a formal mistake, but it is a difference if $q$ is not a prime itself but a prime power.

Comment: the short answer is: no it's not. Even the multiplicative one is not homomorphic, because projecting the elliptic curve point to its x-coordinate is not a homomorphism. Right now I can't think of any structure preserving functions between elliptic curves and their underlying finite field, except pairings. But in pairing friendly group this encryption scheme will probably not work anyway.

Comment: This might be a bit late, but the encryption you mention is apparently not semantically secure. See this answer: [that is an invalid way of combining the point which is the result of the DH exchange with the plaintext](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45000/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves-ii/45011#45011).

Answer (score 5):

As @tylo says, projecting the point to the $x$ coordinate does not give you a homomorphism. So 
this version is not useful if you want to have additively homomorphic ElGamal.

However, you could use the "exponential" version of standard ElGamal on elliptic
curves, i.e., instead of encrypting a message $m$ somehow mapped to a point $M$ on the curve (using an injective efficiently invertible encoding), to encrypt a message $m$ straightforwardly mapped as $M=m\cdot P$ to a point on the curve where $P$ is your generator and $m$ an integer in the order
of the group. This will give you an additive homomorphic encryption
scheme. However, as discussed below, this encoding is not efficiently invertible.

Let $P$ be the generator of your elliptic curve group of prime order $q$ and $Y=xP$ be your 
public key ($x$ the private key). Then given two ciphertexts for messages $m_1,m_2\in Z_q$:

$C_1=(k_1P,m_1P+k_1Y)$ and $C_2=(k_2P,m_2P+k_2Y)$, then by componentwise point addition you receive

$$C=((k_1+k_2)P,(m_1+m_2)P+(k_1+k_2)Y)$$ which is a valid ciphertext for message $m_1+m_2 \mod q$.

You can decrypt $C$, but this obviously gives you $M=(m_1+m_2)P$ and in order to recover 
$m_1+m_2 \mod q$, you have to compute $\log_P M$, i.e., you have to compute discrete logarithms after
encryption. If your messages $m_i$ come from a small set, this, however, is quite efficiently feasible. However, 
this clearly depends on your application, i.e., which values from which range the $m_i$'s can take.