# ElGamal on elliptic curves attack model (CPA,CCA1,CCA2)?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I can't find relevant literature discussing three attack models of the ECC-ElGamal algorithm (CPA, CCA1, CCA2)

ECC-ElGamal algorithm: [ElGamal with elliptic curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves)

I only know that ElGamal belongs to CPA, but I can't determine which one (CPA, CCA1 or CCA2) belongs to in the case of ElGamal on ECC.

It would be better if there is a source of relevant literature!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

In [Tsiounis and Yung's proof of the IND-CPA](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221010812_On_the_Security_of_ElGamal_Based_Encryption) semantic security of El Gamal, the only assumption made is that the decisional Diffie-Hellman problem is hard. The proof transfers easily to any group where the decisional Diffie-Hellman problem is hard, including we believe (non-pairing-friendly) elliptic curve groups.

Similarly all El Gamal instantiations are trivially CCA2 attackable (given a ciphertext $(rG,rA+M)$, request a decryption of (for example) $(2rG,2(rA+M))$ to recover $2M$ and hence $M$.

As far as I know the semantic security of any instance of IND-CPA secure El Gamal under CCA1 is an open problem.

On the pairing-friendly elliptic curve point, note that for such curves there *is* a means of checking whether a given El Gamal encryption is an encryption of a hypothetical message e.g. to check that $(P,Q)=(rG,rA+M)$ compute the pairing of $P$ and $A$ with the pairing of $G$ and $Q-M$. If the equality of the pairing holds, then so does the equality of the encryptions. This is because the decisional Diffie-Hellman problem is soluble in these groups.

Comment: Is the safety of meeting CCA better than CPA?
If CCA is more secure than CPA, is it insecure to only meet CPA encryption?