# ElGamal with elliptic curves for security

Tags: elliptic-curves

I only know that ElGamal belongs to CPA based on DDH or CDH hard problem.

But, if i want to proof the CPA security for ECC-ElGamal, then, what hard problem should i based?DLP?

ECC-ElGamal algorithm: [ElGamal with elliptic curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves)

It would be better if there is a source of relevant literature!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

> But, if i want to proof the CPA security for ECC-ElGamal, then, what hard problem should i based? DLP?

It's fairly easy to show that it is equivalent to the DDH problem.

Reducing CPA security to DDH:

Given a public key $aG$, and the possible encryption of a plaintext $P$, which is $X, Y$; if it is in fact ECC-ElGamal, then $X = bG, Y = abG + P$ for some random $b$.

Then we check whether $aG, X, Y-P$ is an DDH-triplet; it's easy to see that if we were given an ECC-ElGamal ciphertext, then it is.

Reducing DDH to CPA security:

Given a potential DDH-triplet $X, Y, Z$ (which is $aG, bG, abG$ if it is a triplet), then we select an arbitrary plaintext $P$, and pass to our CPA-oracle the public key $X$, and the ciphertext $Y, Z+P$; if it says that this is an El Gamal encryption, then we say that it is a DDH-triplet.

Comment: It's can't based on CDH hard problem?

Comment: @HungLI: see my last paragraph - if you have a DDH oracle, you can distinguish ECElGamal from random.